# C++ how can i loop the function in a class so that i can set more than one estudiante info?

Tags: c++, class, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int x;

class estudiante
{
    private:
        string  nombre,cedula,codigo,direccion;

    public:
       void getDetalles(void);
       void setDetalles(void);
};

void estudiante::getDetalles(void){
    x=0;
    cout << "Ingrese el nombre del estudiante "<<x+1<<":" ;
    cin >> nombre;`
    cout << "Ingrese el numero de cedula: ";
    cin >> cedula;
    cout << "Ingrese el codigo: ";
    cin >> codigo;
    cout << "Ingrese la direccion ";
    cin >> direccion;

}

void estudiante::setDetalles(void){
    cout << "La informacion de estudiante "<<x+1<<": \n";
    cout << "Nombre:"<< nombre<<"\n";
    cout << "Cedula:"<< cedula<<"\n";
    cout << "Codigo:"<< codigo<<"\n";
    cout << "Direccion:"<< direccion<<"\n";

 }

int main()
{
     estudiante std;

    std.getDetalles();
    std.setDetalles();

   return 0;
}
```

This is the code I have but I need to insert like 3 sets of estudiantes then it should print the details(detalles)

[the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZePUU.png)

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Bwa.png)

Comment: Put all students in a container (e.g. std::vector) and loop over them using range based for loops. E.g. std::vector<Student> students, for(Student& student : students) { ... }. Containers : https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::vector<>` to achieve this. Below is the working example. It takes 3 students one by one. You can change the number of students as input to your desired value or even take it from the user.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int x;

class estudiante
{
    private:
        string  nombre,cedula,codigo,direccion;

    public:
       void getDetalles(void);
       void setDetalles(void);
};

void estudiante::getDetalles(void){
    x=0;
    cout << "Ingrese el nombre del estudiante "<<x+1<<":" ;
    cin >> nombre;
    cout << "Ingrese el numero de cedula: ";
    cin >> cedula;
    cout << "Ingrese el codigo: ";
    cin >> codigo;
    cout << "Ingrese la direccion ";
    cin >> direccion;

}

void estudiante::setDetalles(void){
    cout << "La informacion de estudiante "<<x+1<<": \n";
    cout << "Nombre:"<< nombre<<"\n";
    cout << "Cedula:"<< cedula<<"\n";
    cout << "Codigo:"<< codigo<<"\n";
    cout << "Direccion:"<< direccion<<"\n";

 }

int main()
{
    std::vector<estudiante> studentList;//a vector of students 
    //this is the input loop
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)//this loop will create 3 students and push them onto the vector above. You can change the value 3
    {
       estudiante temporarysStdnt;

       temporarysStdnt.getDetalles();
      // temporarysStdnt.setDetalles(); 
       
       studentList.push_back(temporarysStdnt);
    }
    
    //now to output the details of all the students
    for(estudiante& Student: studentList)
    {
        Student.setDetalles();
    }
   return 0;
}
```